# WARNING The requested profile "local" could not be activated

Tags: maven

I've tried executing "mvn" command in the command line and it seems to work correctly because outputs in /target are correct.

```
    mvn -P dev clean package -DskipTests
```

But a warning below is continuously printed at the last line.

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  1.344 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-07T14:22:17+09:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [WARNING] The requested profile "local" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

I obviously declared the profile option as "dev", but this warning says the requested profile is "local".
Why does this warning keep showing and how to disappear?
This is my profile setting in pom.xml

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <env>dev</env>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>real</id>
            <properties>
                <env>real</env>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: The message tells you that you have given somewhere to activate a profile which simply does not exists...either in default goal etc.